# jQuery scroll position history in infinite scroll when go back to previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I scrolling down to the 18/50 of my `<div>` on my Index page then I go to another page in the same tab and go back to previous page.

How do I make a scroll down to the same position on 18/50 of my `<div>`?

**scroll.js**

```
var ajax_arry = [];
var ajax_index = 0;
var sctp = 100;
$(function () {
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "scroll.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "actionfunction=showData&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#demoajax').html(response);

        }

    });
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var height = $('#demoajax').height();
        var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (ajax_arry.length > 0) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            for (var i = 0; i < ajax_arry.length; i++) {
                ajax_arry[i].abort();
            }
        }
        var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
        var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

        if ((($(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight) == $(window).height()) && isload == 'true') {
            $('#loading').show();
            var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
                url: "scroll.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "actionfunction=showData&page=" + page,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
                    $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
                    $('#loading').hide();

                    $('#demoajax').append(response);

                }

            });
            ajax_arry[ajax_index++] = ajaxreq;

        }
        return false;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
            alert("bottom!");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

store the window offset top in localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('windowscrolltop',$(window).scrollTop());
```

and when u came back to the page and binding done animate to that point.

```
var windowscrolltop = localStorage.getItem('windowscrolltop');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: windowscrolltop
}, 500);
```

Comment: i believe you are redirecting the another page from any point before that set the window scrolltop and when you came back to the page when ur data binding complete then animate it